# How to add page dynamic with Vue-turnjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

First of all, I hope everyone understands because my English is poor.
I only display 12 pages at a time. how can i add pages of books taken from api. When I use vue-turnjs, when adding the page to the array the page is not wrapped by class **page-wrapper**

[image]

**index.vue**

```html
<template>
    <fullscreen
        :fullscreen.sync="fullscreen"
        class="flex flex-col justify-between h-full"
    >
        <div class="bg-white">
            <div class="container flex items-center justify-between my-4">
                <div class="flex items-center">
                    <el-tag type="danger">
                        <i class="fas fa-undo-alt" /> Thoát
                    </el-tag>
                    <div class="ml-4 text-lg font-semibold">
                        {{ titleBook }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex items-center">
                    Trang
                    <el-input
                        :value="currentPage"
                        size="small"
                        class="mx-3"
                        style="width: 50px"
                        @input="handleChangePage"
                    />
                    / tổng {{ contentBook.pagination.total }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="flex-grow">
            s
        </div> -->
        <div class="container">
            <ReadItem
                :book-id="book.id"
                :current-page="currentPage"
                :content-book="contentBook"
                class="flex-grow my-4"
                :is-fetching-more-page="isFetchingMorePage"
                @onAddPage="handleAddPage"
                @onChangeCurrentPage="handleChangePage"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white">
            <div class="container flex items-center justify-between my-4">
                <div class="cursor-pointer" @click="toggleFullscreen">
                    <i class="fas fa-expand-arrows-alt" /> Toàn màn hình
                </div>
                <div class="flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-white bg-blue-100 rounded-xl">
                    <i class="mx-2 fas fa-pencil-alt" /> | <i class="mx-2 fas fa-gamepad" /> Làm bài tập
                </div>
                <div class="cursor-pointer" @click="openContentTree($event)">
                    Mục lục
                    <i class="fas fa-bars" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ContentTree
            ref="contentTree"
            :title="book.title"
            :table-of-contents="tableOfContents"
            class="fixed top-0 right-0 h-screen"
            @onMoveToPage="handleChangePage"
        />
    </fullscreen>
</template>

<script>
    import VueFullscreen from 'vue-fullscreen';
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import _last from 'lodash/last';
    import _isNumber from 'lodash/isNumber';
    import ContentTree from '@/components/book/read/ContentTree.vue';
    import ReadItem from '@/components/book/read/Item.vue';
    import { getListBook, getTableContent, getBook } from '@/api/books/index';

    Vue.use(VueFullscreen);

    export default {
        components: {
            ContentTree,
            ReadItem,
        },

        async asyncData({ params, query }) {
            const { page } = query;
            const bookId = _last(params.id.split('-'));
            const { data: { book } } = await getBook(bookId);
            const { data: contentBook } = await getListBook(bookId, 1);
            const { data: { tableOfContents } } = await getTableContent(bookId);
            const currentPage = page ? +page : 1;

            return {
                contentBook,
                currentPage,
                book,
                tableOfContents,
            };
        },

        data: () => ({
            fullscreen: false,
            isFetchingMorePage: false,
        }),

        computed: {
            titleBook() {
                return this.contentBook.rows[0]?.bookTitle;
            },
        },

        methods: {
            openContentTree(event) {
                this.$refs.contentTree.open(event);
            },

            toggleFullscreen() {
                this.fullscreen = !this.fullscreen;
            },

            handleChangePage(value) {
                if (_isNumber(+value) && !Number.isNaN(+value)) {
                    if (+value >= this.contentBook.pagination.total) {
                        this.currentPage = this.contentBook.pagination.total;
                    } else {
                        this.currentPage = +value;
                    }
                }
            },

            async handleAddPage(page) {
                try {
                    this.isFetchingMorePage = true;
                    const { data: contentBook } = await getListBook(this.book.id, page);
                    this.contentBook.rows.push(...contentBook.rows);
                } finally {
                    this.isFetchingMorePage = false;
                }
            },

            changeCurrentPage(currentPage) {
                this.currentPage = currentPage;
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

**ReadItem.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div
        class="relative flex"
    >
        <img
            class="items-baseline m-auto mr-8 cursor-pointer"
            src="@/static/images/book/arrow-left-2.png"
            alt="arrow left"
            @click="handlePrevPage"
        >
        <div
            class="w-full p-3 my-5 rounded-md"
            :style="( !isLast && !isFirst ) && `background: linear-gradient(267.87deg, #336CCE 15.43%, #438AFF 77.02%);`"
            @mousedown.right="handlePreventContext"
            @mouseup.right="handlePreventContext"
            @contextmenu.prevent
        >
            <fw-turn ref="turnRef" class="magazine" :options="options">
                <div
                    v-for="_page in pages"
                    :key="_page.id"
                    class="relative"
                >
                    <img
                        class="w-full h-full"
                        :src="_page.image"
                        alt=""
                    >
                    <div
                        v-if="_page.attachments.length"
                        class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full"
                    >
                        <img
                            v-for="attach in _page.attachments"
                            :key="attach.id"
                            :src="`/images/book/${checkType(attach.type)}.svg`"
                            :alt="attach.horizontalPosition"
                            class="absolute cursor-pointer rounded-2xl"
                            :class="`${checkType(attach.type)}`"
                            :style="{left: `${attach.verticalPosition}%`, top: `${attach.horizontalPosition}%`}"
                        >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fw-turn>
        </div>
        <img
            class="items-baseline m-auto ml-8 cursor-pointer"
            src="@/static/images/book/arrow-right-2.png"
            alt="arrow right"
            @click="handleNextPage"
        >
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    // import { getListBook } from '@/api/books';

    export default {
        props: {
            contentBook: {
                type: Object,
                required: true,
            },
            currentPage: {
                type: Number,
                default: 2,
            },
            bookId: {
                type: [Number, String],
                required: true,
            },
            isFetchingMorePage: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: true,
            },
        },

        data() {
            return {
                fetchingMorePage: false,
                isFirst: true,
                isLast: false,
                options: {
                    display: 'double',
                    acceleration: true,
                    elevation: 50,
                    autoCenter: true,
                    when: {
                        turning: (_, page) => {
                            this.first = false;
                            this.last = false;
                            if (page % 12 === 0) {
                                this.$emit('onAddPage', Math.floor(page / 12) + 1);
                            }
                            this.$emit('onChangeCurrentPage', page);
                        },

                        first: () => {
                            this.first = true;
                        },

                        last: () => {
                            this.last = true;
                        },
                    },
                },
            };
        },

        computed: {
            pages() {
                return this.contentBook.rows.reduce((acc, item) => [...acc, item], []);
            },
        },

        methods: {
            handlePreventContext(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            },

            checkType(type) {
                switch (type) {
                    case 'audio':
                        return 'audio';
                    case 'video':
                        return 'video';
                    case 'html':
                        return 'html';
                    default:
                        return '';
                }
            },

            handlePrevPage() {
                if (this.fetchingMorePage) {
                    this.$message({
                        type: 'info',
                        message: 'Đang tải thêm thông tin sách',
                    });
                }
            },

            handleNextPage() {
                if (this.fetchingMorePage) {
                    this.$message({
                        type: 'info',
                        message: 'Đang tải thêm thông tin sách',
                    });
                } else {
                    this.$refs.turnRef.forceRerender('next');
                }
            },
        },
    };
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.magazine {
  width: 1152px;
  height: 752px;

    .video {
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFB3B3 0%, #FC2020 66.67%);
    }

    .audio {
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, #B3FAFF 0%, #1CB823 66.67%);
    }

    .html {
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, #B3FAFF 0%, #2073FC 66.67%);
    }

    .page {
        box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        background-color: #ccc;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to get pages from api and push it to array client and get above image

Comment: Please provide some code (like a [repro]) and also give us some links to what exactly you're using. Because https://github.com/Reidond/vue-turnjs seems not super well maintained/explained, you may choose something else here.

Comment: So, what is not working exactly? What do you see in your Vue devtools?

Comment: i dont see special in Vue devtools. When adding pages in array then html created dont have <div class="page-wapper">

Comment: you can see gif : https://ezgif.com/gif-to-mp4/ezgif-7-d73c3ff8a899.gif

Comment: This link is not linked to anything at all.

Comment: sorry, link here https://imgur.com/a/XGNsksG